# Scala error : unbound placeholder parameter and pattern matching condition

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, apache-samza

I'm trying to combine pattern matching and condition, but this code (that's a Samza task):

```
override def process(incomingMessageEnvelope: IncomingMessageEnvelope, messageCollector: MessageCollector, taskCoordinator: TaskCoordinator): Unit = {
    val event = (incomingMessageEnvelope getMessage).asInstanceOf[Map[String, Date]]
    val symbol = (event get "symbol").asInstanceOf[String]
    val eventDate = (event get "date").asInstanceOf[Date]

    (store get symbol) match {
      case x: java.util.Date if x.equals(eventDate) || x.after(eventDate) => _ 
      case _ => {
        this.store.put(symbol, eventDate)
      }
    }
  }
```

returns this error:

```
Error:(30, 38) unbound placeholder parameter
  case x if isGreaterOf(x, x) => _
                                 ^
```

Have you any idea of the error?

Thank you

Regards

Gianluca

Comment: You're error doesn't exactly match the example code, but the important question is: what's supposed to happen when the pattern matches and passes the filters (i.e. the `if` conditions)?  What code is supposed to be run?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Exception does not match your code, but there is one line, that would throw the same error:

```
case x: java.util.Date if x.equals(eventDate) || x.after(eventDate) => _
```

because `_` is a placeholder that can be used in patterns for matching and return types. It cannot not be used to indicate a `Unit` return value. To return a `Unit` value without executing code, you could just do

```
case x: java.util.Date if x.equals(eventDate) || x.after(eventDate) => ()
```

instead.

Comment: You can just omit the value completely: `case x: java.util.Date if x.equals(eventDate) || x.after(eventDate) =>` (It'll actually be Unit automatically)

Comment: That is right. However, I prefer to at least write something that makes my intent clear. And `()` is less work than a comment ;)